# Retorno de carro en Windows con Java

Tags: java, formato

os comento, tengo un problema para leer la nueva linea ("\n") en unos ficheros que se generan de forma dinamica con Java.

Os cuento un poco la estructura por encima ya que no os puedo pegar todo el codigo porque son muuuchas lineas en varios archivos:

Tengo un

```
String variable = generarFichero();
```

La funcion generarFichero() a su vez tiene:

```
String parte1 = generaParteUno();
String parte2 = generaParteDos();
String otraCosa = "Loquesea";

return otraCosa.concat(parte1).concat(parte2).concat("\n");
```

La cosa es que al final deberia quedar un fichero cuyo contenido fuese asi mas o menos:
(Imaginaos que los guiones son espacios)

Prueba1----------Datos1---------Datos2

Prueba2----------Datos1---------Datos2

Prueba3----------Datos1---------Datos2

Me entendeis no?

Bien pues si lo abro con algun editor de texto de Linux o con alguno de windows estilo Notepad++, Sublime etc. se ve correctamente sin problemas, pero en el bloc de notas por ser de Windows o no se no se ve asi, se ve sin las nuevas lineas, no se si me explico.

Bien, el problema es que luego ese fichero se manda automaticamente y lo que procesa ese fichero da error porque lo lee de la manera que explico antes, sin saltos de linea, no se si puedo usar algo mas "universal" que el \n para crearlo o si hay alguna manera de hacerlo bien.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en vez de:

```
return otraCosa.concat(parte1).concat(parte2).concat("\n");
```

Proba asi:

```
return otraCosa.concat(parte1).concat(parte2).concat("\r\n");
```

Espero que te funcione, saludos

Comment: Funcionó! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `System.lineSeparator()` que te pone el salto de linea adecuado para el sistema.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247059/is-there-a-newline-constant-defined-in-java-like-environment-newline-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no has incluido parte del código. Asumiendo que están generando los documento con la función BufferedWriter, debería usar el método new line ya que así generarás un salto de línea en el archivo, mientras que "\n" solo es un formato que el bloc de notas no lo reconoce.

Si usas BufferedWriter, deberías añadir esta línea entre archivo:

BufferedWriter bw;

```
for(....) //O la estructura que utilices
   ....
   bw.newLine(); //Esto genera el salto de línea
```